# Put the Query result of MySql in to a C# list or array?

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays

I've done some searching for the answer, but only find a lot of PHP answers. I need this for a C# application. Can any one point me in the right direction?

I'm doing this, but this only returns the first row into my variable:

```
    Query("SELECT SaksNummer FROM casetracking")

    public static string Query(string query)
    {
        string x;
        mysqlCon.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mysqlCon);
        x = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        mysqlCon.Close();
        return x;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ExecuteScalar](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executescalar) is designed to only return one (thus *scalar*) value:

> Executes the query, and returns the
>   first column of the first row in the
>   result set returned by the query.
>   Extra columns or rows are ignored.

Try using [ExecuteReader](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executereader). Example:

```
public void CreateMySqlDataReader(string mySelectQuery, MySqlConnection myConnection) 
 {
    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
      while(myReader.Read()) 
      {
        Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0));
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      myReader.Close();
      myConnection.Close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: An update with new language features could be nice, this is 9 years old now.